# issue facing when run app with any object in viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add ECSlidingViewController in my aap. It works fine when I add no object on my first view controller. But when I add any object like button, navbar, imageview it start giving me error. I try to find error with Try And Catch but no success.I am new, Please help me, and also tell me if there is any much better solution then ECSlidingViewController.
Here is my project file. Thank You
[Project Zip file](https://www.box.com/s/60p0h2lns17vmnv069by)

Comment: the project does not compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this may be unrelated but in line 23 or XYZViewController you have MainStoryBoard and it should be MainStoryboard. That got it to compile and run for me. Also you are using autolayout constraints which only work with 6.0 and above so choose the 6 simulator or go back to what they call 'springs and struts' (the older layout paradigm) by clicking on your storyboard, going to the first of the tabs to the right (looks like a dogeared piece of paper, and unchecking 'use autolayout'.

Hope that helps, or if there is a more sinister problem that you find it.